# Why Odoo shows me the message: Form view couldn't be loaded?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have a button that when pressed opens a view stock.picking model ( stock.picking.form ).
This button and function are in the sale.order.line model.

In the sale.order.form view :

```
<button type='object' name='open_wizard' string="Stock Picking View" icon="fa-arrow-right"/>
```

In the sale.order.line model:

```
@api.multi
def open_wizard(self):
    view_id = self.env.ref('stock.view_picking_form').id
    context = self._context.copy()
    return {
        'name':'Stock Picking Form',
        'view_type':'form',
        'view_mode':'tree',
        'views' : [(view_id,'form')],
        'res_model':'stock.picking',
        'view_id':view_id,
        'type':'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_id':self.id,
        'target':'new',
        'context':context,
    }
```

When I press the button, Odoo shows me the following message:
**Form view couldn't be loaded**
[image]

If someone could help me, to correct any errors . Because I don't understand why Odoo shows me the message above . Thank you so much.

Comment: What is stack trace of error in server logs?

Comment: console shows nothing

Comment: hey! @MuhammadTahir help me please with this.

Comment: Why you are using `self.id` for an other model ?

Answer (score 1):

I had created a button for redirecting to form view.May be you can use this code as reference.
This is my xml file,

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_census_form">
            <field name="name">census.form</field>
            <field name="model">census</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="census">
            <group>
                <field name="first_name" style="width: 40%"/>
                <field name="last_name" style="width: 40%"/>
                <field name="birth_date" style="width: 40%"/>       
                <field name="address" style="width: 40%"/>
                <field name="phone" style="width: 40%"/>
                <field name="email" style="width: 40%"/>  
                <button type="object" string="Form2" name="redirection"/>
            </group>    
            </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

.py file,

```
    @api.multi
    def redirection(self):
        view_id = self.env.ref('census.view_census_form').id


        return {
            'name':'census.form',
            'view_type':'form',
            'view_mode':'form',
            'views' : [(view_id,'form')],
            'res_model':'census',
            'view_id':view_id,
            'type':'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_id':self.id,
            'target':'current',

        }
```

Comment: Please review my new answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was have same problem and It was In the res_id : self.Id after I change It It to `'res_id':self.cash_policy_ids.id,` I my case Its work I hope this can help you

Answer (score -1):

Odoo I still continued showing me the same message : **Form view Could not be loaded** . Maybe they are missing parameters to add to the function and does not recognize the view.

This is my code:
[In my sale.py]

```
@api.multi
def redirection(self):
    view_id = self.env.ref('stock.view_picking_form').id
    return {
        'name':'stock.picking.form',
        'view_type':'form',
        'view_mode':'form',
        'views' : [(view_id,'form')],
        'res_model':'stock.picking',
        'view_id':view_id,
        'type':'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_id':self.id,
        'target':'current',
    }
```

[In my sale.order.form view ]

```
<button type="object" string="Form Stock Picking" name="redirection"/>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please, don't answer with a question. Extend you already made answer